# PartialView to Full view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

I needed two models in my view. So, as I was suggested, I created two partial views : Entete and ChampsFormulaireInvalidite, both with their models.

My Index View render these two views:

```
<head>
    <title>Formulaire d'invalidité</title>
</head>

@{Html.RenderAction("Entete");}
@{Html.RenderAction("ChampsFormulaireInvalidite");}
```

In the Entete controller, I sometime catch an exception. When it does, I would like the entire page to be replaced by an error page. I tried this:

```
 public PartialViewResult Entete()
     {
         try{ 
             <some actions>
              return PartialView ("Entete", model)
            }
         catch(Exception){
              return PartialView ("Error")
            }
     }
```

Of course, since I return a PartialView, only the first half of my page displays the error view, while the other half displays a form (ChampsFormulaireInvalidite view). I would like to be redirected to a full error page when an exception is catched.

Any suggestion?

I tried to put a try catch in my index method with no success:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {    
         try{
             return View("Index");   
            }
         catch(Exception){return View("Error")}
    }
```

Comment: As much as possible, when you want to handle errors in a way that touches the infrastructure (in this case, the views), use a "global" error handler, such as the HandleError attribute or Application_Error in Global.asax.cs.

Comment: Your first example is written to return a partial view, so that error page will appear as a partial, because you're returning a PartialView.  Further to this, you're calling the action from `RenderAction` so no matter what is returned, it's going to appear within the page.  What happens if you just leave it as an unhandled exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNEjXCSnw6w

As suggested, I turned on the customErrors in my web.config:

```
<system.web>
 ...
    <customErrors mode="On" />
</system.web>
```

And added an Error.cshtml view under Views/Shared:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Erreur";
}
<h1 class="text-danger">Error</h1>
```